# Como puedo cargar o llenar datos de un String[], desde el servidor?

Tags: java, android, array

Estoy realizando a un `ListView Expandable`, pero cuando intento subir los datos del servidor no me funciona solo con datos estáticos. Alguna sugerencia?

Esta la clase MainActivity

```
String[] parent;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        Hijos();

        secondLevel.add(blusas);
    secondLevel.add(accesorio);



    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[0], Escote);
    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[1], Larga);
    thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[2], Corta);

    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[0], Collar);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[1], Reloj);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[2], Anillo);
    thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[3], Pulsera);

    data.add(thirdLevelAccesorio);
    data.add(thirdLevelBlusas);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandible_listview);

    ThreeLevelListAdapter threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = new ThreeLevelListAdapter(this, parent, secondLevel, data);


    expandableListView.setAdapter( threeLevelListAdapterAdapter );

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });


}

public void Hijos() {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Categorias.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {

                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);
                        String returnState= j.getString("returnState");
                        String returnData= j.getString("returnData");

                        JSONObject mainObject= new JSONObject(returnData);

                       Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext()) {

                            String key = keys.next();
                            Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);

                            String cate_name= jsonObject1.getString("cate_name");
                            String cate_id= jsonObject1.getString("cate_shop_id");
                         parent=new String[]{cate_id};
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," : "+n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            ,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Verifique su conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("id",id);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Creating RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

}
```

clase **ThreeLevelListAdapter**

```
public class ThreeLevelListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    String[] parentHeaders;
    List<String[]> secondLevel;
    private Context context;
    List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data;

    public ThreeLevelListAdapter(Context context, String[] parentHeader, List<String[]> secondLevel, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data) {
        this.context = context;

        this.parentHeaders = parentHeader;

        this.secondLevel = secondLevel;

        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentHeaders.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {


        // no idea why this code is working

        return 1;

    }

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int group, int child) {


    return child;


}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowParentText);
        text.setText(this.parentHeaders[groupPosition]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(context);

    String[] headers = secondLevel.get(groupPosition);


    List<String[]> childData = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String[]> secondLevelData=data.get(groupPosition);

    for(String key : secondLevelData.keySet())
    {


        childData.add(secondLevelData.get(key));

    }



    secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context, headers,childData));

    secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);


    secondLevelELV.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                secondLevelELV.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });


    return secondLevelELV;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}}
```

[image: Logcat-Error]

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué significa "no funciona"? ¿Muestra datos en blanco/no muestra datos/la aplicación lanza una excepción/etc? En todo caso, es una buena que limites el ámbito del problema haciendo pruebas con valores estáticos.

Comment: a que se refieren con valores estaticos como un `public static String VALOR_ESTATICO=""`

Comment: bueno me imagino que son valores de prueba

Comment: Si son valores de prueba que agrego al array, el problema esta en q los datos los necesitó del servidor y cuando los cargo y los agrego al array se sale la app, arroja un error

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos la salida de la consola del depurador?

Answer (score 0):

Eso es debido a que el String[] parent, lo estas cargando con una tarea asincrona, en otras palabras tu lista se crea mientras todavia ni siquiera tienes los datos del servidor, por eso es que te crea vacia la lista.

Lo que tienes que hacer:

1.- Crear el adapter y declaralo afuera de la clase para que tengas acceso a la variable al momento de traer los datos del servidor con el String[] parent vacio

```
ThreeLevelListAdapter threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = new ThreeLevelListAdapter(this, parent, secondLevel, data);

expandableListView.setAdapter( threeLevelListAdapterAdapter );
```

2- Luego debes obtener los datos del servidor.

```
getHijos();
```

3.- Y una vez q tienes los hijos solo debes actualizar tu adapter con los datos obtenidos en el servidor

```
public void Hijos() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Categorias.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {

                            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);
                            String returnState = j.getString("returnState");
                            String returnData = j.getString("returnData");

                            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(returnData);

                            Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();
                            while (keys.hasNext()) {

                                String key = keys.next();
                                Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);

                                String cate_name = jsonObject1.getString("cate_name");
                                String cate_id = jsonObject1.getString("cate_shop_id");
                                parent = new String[]{cate_id};
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " : " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //agregar esta linea, permite la actualizacion del adapter una vez obtine los datos del server
                            threeLevelListAdapterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                ,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("id", id);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Tu codigo deberia quedar de esta manera:

```
String[] parent;
    ThreeLevelListAdapter threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        Hijos();

        secondLevel.add(blusas);
        secondLevel.add(accesorio);


        thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[0], Escote);
        thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[1], Larga);
        thirdLevelBlusas.put(blusas[2], Corta);

        thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[0], Collar);
        thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[1], Reloj);
        thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[2], Anillo);
        thirdLevelAccesorio.put(accesorio[3], Pulsera);

        data.add(thirdLevelAccesorio);
        data.add(thirdLevelBlusas);

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandible_listview);

        threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = new ThreeLevelListAdapter(this, parent, secondLevel, data);


        expandableListView.setAdapter(threeLevelListAdapterAdapter);

        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        });


    }

    public void Hijos() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Categorias.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {

                            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);
                            String returnState = j.getString("returnState");
                            String returnData = j.getString("returnData");

                            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(returnData);

                            Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();
                            while (keys.hasNext()) {

                                String key = keys.next();
                                Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);

                                String cate_name = jsonObject1.getString("cate_name");
                                String cate_id = jsonObject1.getString("cate_shop_id");
                                parent = new String[]{cate_id};
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " : " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //agregar esta linea, permite la actualizacion del adapter una vez obtine los datos del server
                            threeLevelListAdapterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                ,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verifique su conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("id", id);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

La clave de todo esta en el threeLevelListAdapterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() esto permitira actualizar tu adapter cuando obtenga los datos de tu servidor por ende tu lista igual se actualizara.

Comment: Es decir, tengo que crear una nuevo adaptador para los datos que recibo del servidor, y luego hacer el llamado desde el MainActivity.

Comment: Primero tienes tu asynctask q es el que carga los datos del servidor en caso que no traiga ningun dato verificamos si existe en cache para cargar esos datos. El main activity solo hace el llamado de ese asynctask, mientras que el asynctask vera que dato entregar si los datos del servidor o del cache. Saludos

Comment: No hay otra forma de hacerlo sin usar asynctask, porque lo que no quiero es cambiar todo.

Comment: Perdona, me confundi con otra pregunta que estaba respondiendo, respondiendo a la primera pregunta q hiciste, no necesitas crear un nuevo adaptador, puedes utilizar el mismo adaptador, si revisas el ultimo fragmento de codigo q envie ahi estoy usando solo un adaptador, solo que cuando actualiza sus datos con el servidor al adaptador le notifico que hubo cambios y ese metodo automaticamente refresca la lista y todo, este es el metodo que actualiza tu adaptador notifyDataSetChanged();, Con el ultimo fragmento de codigo deberia funcionar si lo copias tal cual esta ahi.

Comment: Lo intente hacer de esa manera, pero se detiene la app. Arriba agregue lo que me arroja logcat, al correr la app.

Comment: Eso es porque la primera linea donde dice String[] parert, es nulo cuando se crea la lista, simplemente inicializa la variable String[] parent = new String[]{};

Comment: Pues si eso era, pero pareciera que en realidad no actualiza o guarda los datos en String [], esto es lo que guarda parent [Ljava.lang.String;8d54491